# Show that $M$ is the set of all elements in $R$ which don't have a left multiplicative inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with unity which contains exactly one maximal left ideal $M$. I'm trying to prove that $M$ is the set of all elements in $R$ which don't have a left multiplicative inverse.

So I assumed that $m\in M$ has a left multiplicative inverse. So there is $a\in R$ such that $am=1$, but I cannot see how this leads to contradiction. Can I continue with this?

Answer (score 1):

If $m\in M$ has a left inverse then it can't belong to $M$. Otherwise, since $M$ is a left ideal we would get $1=am\in M$, and so $r=r1\in M$ for all $r\in R$. So this would imply $M=R$, a contradiction to $M$ being maximal. (a maximal ideal is proper)

The interesting direction is that if $m\in M$ has no left inverse then $m\in M$. Well, if $m$ has no left inverse then using Zorn's lemma (a standard argument) one can show that $m$ must belong to some maximal left ideal. However, by assumption $M$ is the only maximal left ideal, so we must have $m\in M$.

Comment: How $1=am\in M$? Isn't it, since $M$ is a left ideal then $ma\in M$ for every $a\in R$?

Comment: $M$ being a left ideal means that $rM\subseteq M$ for every $r\in R$. In particular, if $m\in M$ then $am\in M$ as well.